# can anyone please tell me why this code is isn't producing the right output?

Tags: c++, arrays, break

Problem statement:

---

Check if two arrays are equal or not.Two arrays are said to be equal if both of them contain same set of elements, arrangements (or permutation) of elements may be different though.

This is the snippet of my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t; cin>>t; 
    while(t--)
    {
        int n,i; 
        cin>>n; 
        int arr1[n],arr2[n]; 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr1[i];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr2[i]; 
        sort(arr1,arr1+n); 
        sort(arr2,arr2+n); 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(arr1[i]!=arr2[i])
             break;
            i++;
        }
        if(i==n) cout<<"1\n"; 
        else cout<<"0\n"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For Input:
2      [ number of test cases ]

---

5      [ size of the array for test case #1 ]

---

1 2 5 4 0    [ array 1 ]

---

2 4 5 0 1   [ array 2 ]

---

3            [ size of the array for test case #1 ]

---

1 2 5         [ array 1 ]

---

2 4 15       [ array 2 ]

---

Expected Output

---

1

---

0

---

My code's output

---

0

---

0

Comment: Too many `i++` for one thing.

Comment: Yes. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as your C++ compiler, compile with  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Answer (score 1):

You donot have to increment i++ again inside for loop.

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++) //As,i already gets incremented here
        {
            if(arr1[i]!=arr2[i])
             break;
          // i++;
        }
```